# Netlogo: Selecting an agent based on multiple conditions

Tags: netlogo

I have 2 agents, **hub** and **individual**.

Individuals have its own variable called **value**.

I want to write a method that allow hub to select the individual with the highest **value** and has not established a link with the hub, in order to establish a link with it.

So far I am using max-one-of, which gives me the highest **value**-d individual the first round but on the second round the same individual is still selected despite a link has been already established with the hub.

I would like to ask all how do I get the individual that has not been linked with the hub yet, with the highest **value**?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter your individuals using [`with`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#with) and [`link-neighbor?`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#link-neighbor):

```
breed [ hubs hub ]
breed [ individuals individual ]
individuals-own [ value ]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-hubs 1
  create-individuals 10 [
    set value random 100
    forward 5
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask hubs [
    let candidates individuals with [ not link-neighbor? myself ]
    if any? candidates [
      create-link-with max-one-of candidates [ value ]
    ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

Comment: Thank you, it works!

Let me ask another question:
Each of this links has a variable called **strength**, how can I access a particular link, based on the individual i identified, in order to increase its strength?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you'd better open up a separate question for that. You should also try to familiarize yourself with all the links primitive (http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#linkgroup) in NetLogo. Very often, working with links is just a matter of finding the right primitive to do what you want to do.